# Select2 Jquery ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

Im having terrible trouble with getting the ajax attached to the select2 to fire. The select2 box is rendering correctly, however there is no call made to the controller when searching .

I have taken this from a working example in another project...which makes it all the more confusing

here are the JavaScript and css files in the layout header

```
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.js"></script>
```

here is my input

```
<input type="hidden" id="companyname" name="companyname" style="width: 100%;" />
```

here is my ajax call

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#companyname").select2({
        placeholder: "Type to find a Provider",
        theme: "bootstrap",
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        ajax: {
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            typ8e: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("/CompanyHouse/SearchCompany")",
            data: function(params){
                return { companyname: params.term };
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {
                return { results: data };
            }
        }
        //    formatResult: contractFormatResult,
        //formatSelection: contractFormatSelection,
        //escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- You have a typo on ajax options `type:"GET"`
- The correct way to use `Url.Action` is `'@Url.Action("YourAction","YourController")'`